# MailApp.sendEmail (..., ..., ..., {htmlBody: body}) is it possible to use css?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to use css in the variable i use that keeps html data with google apps script in a spreadsheet? It seems to ignore the `<style>..</style>` section completely. Anyone else tried this?  I'm trying to format the confirmation email to have some nice looks. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with Google Apps Script.

Gmail strips `<style>` tags when *displaying* any email.
You need to use inline styles.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can still do inline styles and embed your script parameters within:

```
    function sendMeMail() {
       ...
// form HTML
       var htmlBodyText = wrapHTML();
       ...
// send email

       MailApp.sendEmail(
           imail,
           subject,
           subject,
             { htmlBody: htmlBodyText,
               inlineImages: 
                   { Logo: myLogo

                   },
               noReply: true
             }
       );
    ...
    }
```

For illustration purposes: you can see how different css style and color formats are used

```
    function wrapHTML() {

       //initialize static parameters
       var myNumbers = new staticNumbers();
       var myPatterns = new staticPatterns();
       var myStyles = new staticStyles();



      var htmlBodyText = '<img src="cid:myLogo" style="background-color:'+myStyles.colorSheetLogo+'">';

      htmlBodyText += '<hr style="height:2px;border-width:2;color:"f8cB9c";background-color:rgb(135,206,250)" /><br><br>';
      htmlBodyText += '<a href='+myPatterns.myUrl+' style="font-size:150%">Hello! </a>'+'<br><br>';

      htmlBodyText += '<table border="1 cellpadding="20"">';

      htmlBodyText += '<colgroup span="'+myNumbers.numberOfColumns+'" <col style="background-color:'+myStyles.colorBgTitleRow+'"> </colgroup>';

      return(htmlBodyText);


     }
```